# Wanting ASP.NET Core Middleware to run after MVC Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I want to have a MiddleWare module run in ASP.NET Core after the MVC Razor View Engine has processed data.  I can get it to run but it seems to not have collected all the data.  I have a Tag Helper that that updates an DI object's collection but when the Middleware runs, the DI object's collection is empty.  My startup.cs looks like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    { 
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

And My MiddleWare is this:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate nextMiddleware;
    private readonly IScriptManager _scriptManager;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IScriptManager scriptManager)
    {
        this.nextMiddleware = next;
        _scriptManager = scriptManager;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var cnt = _scriptManager.ScriptTexts.Count;
        .. get HTML
        Stream originalStream = context.Response.Body;
        ...
        .. update HTML
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(htmlData);
```

I do get the HTML I want but it seems that the collection in my DI does not get updated.

*** Notes - Possible but not working Result Filter

```
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AppendToHtmlBodyFilter());
        });

public class AppendToHtmlBodyFilter : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IScriptManager _scriptManager;

    public AppendToHtmlBodyFilter():base(typeof(SampleActionFilterImpl))
    {
    }

    private class SampleActionFilterImpl : IResultFilter
    {
        private readonly IScriptManager _scriptManager;

        public SampleActionFilterImpl(IScriptManager scriptManager)
        {
            _scriptManager = scriptManager;
            //_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SampleActionFilterAttribute>();
        }

        public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
            var cnt = _scriptManager.ScriptTexts.Count;
            Stream originalStream = context.HttpContext.Response.Body;
            using (MemoryStream newStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Body = newStream;
                context.HttpContext.Response.Body = originalStream;
                newStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(newStream);
                var htmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know there is no way to run a middleware after mvc in request pipeline. If you want to manipulate razor output, you can use filters. Result filter seems suitable for your case.

> Result filters are ideal for any logic that needs to directly surround
>   view execution or formatter execution. Result filters can replace or
>   modify the action result that's responsible for producing the
>   response.

See official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#result-filters

Also see how to use dependency injection with a filter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#dependency-injection

**Update**

I couldn't get it work with result filter(it worked json result but didn't work viewresult).

However i found a good example with middleware: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/269/asp-net-5-middleware-or-where-has-my-httpmodule-gone

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate nextMiddleware;
    private readonly IScriptManager _scriptManager;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IScriptManager scriptManager)
    {
       this.nextMiddleware = next;
       _scriptManager = scriptManager;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
       var cnt = _scriptManager.ScriptTexts.Count;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var bodyStream = context.Response.Body;
            context.Response.Body = memoryStream;

            await _next(context);

            var isHtml = context.Response.ContentType?.ToLower().Contains("text/html");
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 200 && isHtml.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                    {
                        var responseBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        // update html
                        using (var amendedBody = new MemoryStream())
                        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(amendedBody))
                        {
                            streamWriter.Write(responseBody);
                            amendedBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            await amendedBody.CopyToAsync(bodyStream);
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @ademcaglin and thanks. I've manged to write a OnResultExecuted filter but I'm not getting in my htmlData the processed razor html (I'm getting empty string).  How can I write an action filter that captures and updates the html that is processed by razor?  It's not clear to me where the filters execute and how to put mine in a place that I can capture html and update it.  I've updated by question with a "Possible but not working Filter code".

Comment: You are right. It seems it doesn't work for razor output. However i found a solution for middleware approach and it worked as expected. See my update.